# Sharepoint and SQL server Endpoint

Tags: sql-server, web-services, sharepoint, stored-procedures, endpoints

I created a **LinkedServer** on MS SQL Server 2005 pointing to my *Active Directory*. Nothing too fancy. Simple **LinkedServer** with *ReadOnlyAdmin* Account assigned to **CONNECTAS** Property.

Then I created some storedprocedures to retreive some data from the LinkedServer. Again nothing too fancy. Just a few simple *LDAP* Queries.

Then I created a *SQL Endpoint* to expose these stored procedures as Web services. Using Visual Studio 2008, everything is fine and dandy. It finds the endpoint, gets the list of the methods available and runs smoothly. Cool.

But the *Sharpeoint Add Web Service* somehow doesn't work! It finds the *WSDL* file no prob. Retrieves the list of functions and parameterss n all but just simply doesn't run them! Any advice or where I should start checking?

Comment: I'll appreciate if someone with an idea can email me. Thanks.

Comment: We don't work via email here, this is a web site.  Can you post the exact errors that you get?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but from my experience, it's not possible to access sql endpoints from a SharePoint site if the SQL Server and the SharePoint server are not one and the same.